# Listar as respostas conforme o número de questões

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$array = array("","A","B","C","D","E");

for($contar = 1; $contar <= 10; $contar++){

}
```

Cada $contar corresponde ao número das perguntas. Ex.: 1 = Quem nasceu primeiro. 2 = Quem descobriu o Brasil...

Gostaria que ficasse da seguinte forma:

```
    "Pergunta 1";
    "A: <input type='radio' name='respostas[]' value='A'>";
    "B: <input type='radio' name='respostas[]' value='B'>";
    "C: <input type='radio' name='respostas[]' value='C'>";
    ....
"Pergunta 2";
    "A: <input type='radio' name='respostas[]' value='A'>";
    "B: <input type='radio' name='respostas[]' value='B'>";
    "C: <input type='radio' name='respostas[]' value='C'>";
```

Estou meio perdido no for().

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, cada pergunta vai ter o alfabeto todo de opções?

Comment: Olá Igor. O alfabeto vai de A a E. Serao apenas 5 respostas. Vou editar a minha dúvida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa de 2 `fors` o que você já tem para iterar a pergunta e outro internamente para iterar as opções de resposta!

```
$array = array("A","B","C","D","E");
    for($contar = 1; $contar <= 10; $contar++){
        echo "Pergunta " . $contar . "<br>";
        foreach ($array as $opcao) {
            echo $opcao . ": <input type='radio' name='respostas[]' value='" . $opcao ."'>" . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Internamente usei um [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) que acho mais fácil para iterar `arrays`.

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
for($contar = 1; $contar <= 10; $contar++){
    echo" Pergunta $contar ";
    for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++){
        echo"$array[$i]:<input type='radio' name='respostas[]' value='$array[$i]'> ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos. As duas opções funcionaram.